# Debug symbols in anonymous namespace

Tags: c++, visual-studio, namespaces, visual-studio-debugging

In Visual Studio debugger, I seem to be unable to inspect the value of data defined in an anonymous namespace. For instance:

```
namespace minionfarts {
namespace {    
int num_farts = 50;
}

int amplify_farts() {
    return num_farts * 1000; // <-- set breakpoint here
}
}

int main() {
    return minionfarts::amplify_farts();
}
```

when I hit a breakpoint the value of `num_farts` is not displayed in local symbols table. Also I'm unable to add it to the watch table. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: you can't watch the `num_farts` in the debugger, it is still not supported (as of 2017). Please refer to this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/expressions-in-the-debugger?view=vs-2017#c-expressions

Comment: Oh, that's disappointing! I guess we'll have world peace before a properly functional Visual Studio. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can use CLion with mingw.

But I agree ideally Microsoft should fix this bug.

[image: clion]